# Taxonomy classification of blast output

Tags: python, taxonomy

I am trying to do a taxonomic classification of my blast output, using scripts on this web-site https://github.com/bartaelterman/BlastTaxonomy.
I am quite new to python and sometimes I try to find already existing scripts to do complicated jobs. However, scripts like this confuse me a lot. I have a very basic question, i.e. in the script below, where do I replace with my input file, can you give me a short explanation of the script like this to have an idea?

Also, if you have any other ideas how to do it, would be great!

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./scripts")
import blasthittaxonomy

def checkarguments():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "usage: ./addTaxonomyToBlastOutput.py <blast output file>"
        sys.exit(-1)

def main():
    checkarguments()
    taxfetcher = blasthittaxonomy.TaxonomyFetcher()
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    infile = open(filename)
    header = infile.readline()
    print "\t".join(["seqnr", "hitginr", "hitname", "evalue", "bitscore", "similarity", "score",    "division", "scientificName", "rank1", "rank2"])
    for line in infile:
        newline = line.rstrip("\n")
        seqnr, ginr, hitname, evalue, bitscore, sim, score = newline.split("\t")
        division = ""
        scientName = ""
        rank1 = ""
        rank2 = ""
        if ginr != "":
        taxonomy = taxfetcher.getTaxonomy(int(ginr))
        if taxonomy != "":
            scientName = taxonomy[0]["ScientificName"]
            if scientName == "unidentified":
             scientName = ""
            else:
             division = taxonomy[0]["Division"]
             try:
                    rank1 = taxonomy[0]["LineageEx"][0]["ScientificName"]
             except:
             rank1 = ""
             try:
                    rank2 = taxonomy[0]["LineageEx"][1]["ScientificName"]
             except:
             rank2 = ""
    print "\t".join([seqnr, ginr, hitname, evalue, bitscore, sim, score, division, scientName, rank1, rank2])
taxfetcher.die()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't replace anything, just run the script with your file name as a command-line argument

That's where the script reads the input file name:

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: script.py <my_filename> ?

Comment: @user3224522: yes. This script even prints out an error message if you don't provide a command line argument (`"usage: ./addTaxonomyToBlastOutput.py <blast output file>"`). Have you tried to run it?

Comment: do I have to add 'python' in front? anyway for now doesnt seem to work

Comment: it depends:) If you're using linux and your script contains a line like `#!/usr/bin/env python` then you don't have to add `python` in front. Otherwise, here is an example usage (linux with current directory containing the script): `python ./addTaxonomyToBlastOutput.py /home/user/blast/input.txt`

Comment: `chmod +x ./addTaxonomyToBlastOutput.py`

Comment: THANK YOU!! it doesnt show me anything, no result, no error, I guess I am doing something wrong..

Comment: `chmod` shouldn't show anything, it only changes the access permissions of the script. In unix/linux you can't run a script without permission to execute, that's why you got `Permission denied`. Run the `chmod` command once an you will be able to execute the script. Or just use `python` in front.

Comment: thank you Marcin!! it gives me some error but due to script which I need to modify, the important point was to understand how to run it. And in 10 min with you I understood a lot more!